# DataTable select Method has changed string to DBNull

Tags: c#

Datatable has a value with string type.

And when I use select method, the selected rows has a `{} DBNull` instead of `string`.

My code:

```
  dtGo.Rows.InsertAt(_drGo, 0);
  string _filter = "CODE = '" + _code + "'";
  DataRow[] _drArray = dtGo.Select(_filter);
```

and when I'm debugging, the variables are as following

```
   dtGo.Rows[0]  
     ItemArray    
       [3]  "151453" object{string}
   _drArray[0].ItemArray
     [3]  {}       object{System.DBNull}
```

I'm using select method many times. But this case, I have no idea.
Please tell me why select changed the string value to DBNull.

Comment: If you loading data from database `string` can be represented as `DbNull` if value is `NULL` in database.

Comment: in my question, typing error.... Not Int, but string...

Comment: [3] "151453" object{string} is the value of my datatable dtGo. So, value is not Null. I captured this while debugging in visual studio.

Comment: Are you sure about the column name CODE, and the value of _code. And your second column type is int but you are writing where condition in apostrophes(string). Try setting the filter as "CODE= 151453" NOT "CODE = '151453'"

Answer (score 0):

Type of your column (CODE) is int.It can be seen from your watch values

```
 dtGo.Rows[0]  
   ItemArray    
     [3]  "151453" object{int}
```

So you need to compare with an integer value not string. Try

```
  dtGo.Rows.InsertAt(_drGo, 0);
  string _filter = "CODE = " + _code ;
  DataRow[] _drArray = dtGo.Select(_filter);
```

If type of this column should be string check your table definition.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

But Please note that _drArray is the results of filtering.
If filter has a problem, I can't get _drArray.

What I want to know is the reason why select method missed a certain column's value.

You can see the datatable dtGo and selected rows _drArray have the same value of column [0], [1], [2].
But not column [3].

151453 is already stored in datatable. And already filtered to _drArray.
So, I can see the column [0], [1], [2] have values.

ps. there are some Korean language in my code. So, I re-typed variable names. Maybe that confused you. And filtering column name is another one, now shown in question.